# Keeping existing site URLs after migration

Tags: wordpress, url, joomla, migration, hosting

I have a site on the Joomla CMS. I want to migrate the site over to WordPress, for various reasons. The WordPress site will sit within the same hosting account. However, I want to keep the existing URLs of the Joomla site, and avoid having to redirect to new URLs - is this possible?

My existing URLs (on the Joomla site) look like this:

- mysite.com
- mysite.com/dogs
- mysite.com/cats
- mysite.com/birds
- etc.

My WordPress URLs (temporarily) look like this:

- wpstage.mysite.com
- wpstage.mysite.com/dogs/
- wpstage.mysite.com/cats/
- wpstage.mysite.com/birds/
- etc.

I have built a copy of the site in WordPress, on a sub domain of the Joomla site. I plan to transfer it to the root domain and replace the Joomla site which currently sits there.

How do I go about retaining the same URLs for the WordPress version of the site?